# Eclipse + CDT лепит ошибки.

Tags: cdt, c, eclipse

Суть проблемы в следующем: в некоем заголовке есть дефайны. Пути к заголовкам в настройках указаны, более того, сборка проходит как надо. Но в `Problems` eclipse пишет ошибки на все символы.

Symbol 'DDRA' could not be resolved

Не то чтобы большая проблема, но напрягает, да и разобраться охота. В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 1):

Проблема решена частичным отключением Code Analalyse. Обходной путь конечно, но если ошибки есть они и при компиляции вылезут. В общем меня устроило.